# Explicit descriptions of $\mathbb{C}[[h]] \bmod \mathbb{C}[h]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

I'm hoping somebody can give me some insight into the quotient group $\frac{\mathbb{C}[[h]]}{\mathbb{C}[h]}$ where $K=\mathbb{C}[[h]]$ is the complex algebra of complex formal series in one variable $H$ and $\mathbb{C}[h]$ is the algebra of complex polynomials in one variable $h$.

The motivation for my question comes in trying to understand the natural isomorphism between the inverse limit of the system $(\frac{C[h]}{(h^n)})_{n \geq 0}$  and $C[[h]]$. For $f \in C[[h]]$, this map is given by $\pi(f) = (f_0, f_1, f_2, \cdots)$ where $f_i = f$ mod $(h^n)$, so my original question is really about trying to understand the element $f_0$.

Comment: I think $f_i$ should be given by$f_i=f \bmod h^{n+1}$ (i.e. you truncate the formal power series after degree $n$).

Comment: Ah, you are very correct. Thank you!

Comment: This is a strange question, like asking for an explicit description of $\mathbf R/\mathbf Q$ or $\mathbf Z_p/\mathbf Z$ where $\mathbf Z_p$ is the $p$-adic integers. Whatever basic problem you are trying to solve, going down the path of using $\mathbf C[[h]]/\mathbf C[h]$ is a mistake.  You say that you are "trying to understand the natural isomorphism $\pi \colon \mathbf C[[h]] \to \varprojlim \mathbf C[h]/(h^n)$".  Can you explain in your question what you do not understand about the map $\pi$?  Do you see why a power series in $\mathbf C[[h]]$ modulo a power of $h$ is a polynomial?

Comment: I think $\mathbb{C}[[h]]$ mod $\mathbb{C}[h]$ will be zero, because given any formal series, every finite part of it is $0$ mod $\mathbb{C}[h]$. Bernards observation made my question irrelevant though. I don't know if the quotient in my question makes sense, since the numerator is just a formal series where the denominator is analyitcally defined, so there are some technical issues perhaps.